# Create sub-group with indexes

Tags: python, performance, indexing, time, slice

I have a time series of `0's` and `1's` in python. This shows the error status of a machine at certain intervals. It means that it gave 1 error.

What I want to do here is to divide this data into 10 subgroups and find the percentage of errors (i.e, `1's`) occurring in each group in that subgroup. Indexes are increased by 1 while creating subgroups.

In other words, the first 10 values ​​with index number `0-9` should be the first group, the second 10 values ​​with index number `1-10` should be the second group, and the third 10 values ​​with index number `2-11` should be the third group. Can you help me?

My data like this.

```
001100111100001111110
```

The result I want:

```
1.group:0011001111
2.group:0110011110
3.group:1100111100
4.group:1001111000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list slices to get your required groups -

```
data = ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0']
groups = []
for x in range(len(data) - 9):
    groups.append(''.join(data[x:10+x]))
print(groups)

for i, group in enumerate(groups):
    print(f"Group{i}: {group}")
```

**Output:**

```
['0011001111', '0110011110', '1100111100', '1001111000', '0011110000', '0111100001', '1111000011', '1110000111', '1100001111', '1000011111', '0000111111', '0001111110']
Group0: 0011001111
Group1: 0110011110
Group2: 1100111100
Group3: 1001111000
Group4: 0011110000
Group5: 0111100001
Group6: 1111000011
Group7: 1110000111
Group8: 1100001111
Group9: 1000011111
Group10: 0000111111
Group11: 0001111110
```

If you don't want the strings and instead want a list of each subgroup then you can replace `groups.append(''.join(data[x:10+x]))` with `groups.append(data[x:10+x]))`

---

Follow-up to print the error ratio in each group, count number of 1's and then divide it by observations in the group -

```
for i, group in enumerate(groups):
    error_ratio = group.count('1')/len(group)
    print(f"Group{i} error ratio: {error_ratio}")
```

**Output:**

```
Group0 error ratio: 0.6
Group1 error ratio: 0.6
Group2 error ratio: 0.6
Group3 error ratio: 0.5
Group4 error ratio: 0.4
Group5 error ratio: 0.5
Group6 error ratio: 0.6
Group7 error ratio: 0.6
Group8 error ratio: 0.6
Group9 error ratio: 0.6
Group10 error ratio: 0.6
Group11 error ratio: 0.6
```

Comment: Thank you Jay. Totally solved my problem.But one more question I have: I want to ratio of 1' for each gruop and visualize this ratios. For ex gruop1  ratio is 0.6.(6-1,4-0 total 10).So I can see the trends.

Comment: Sure, you can get it as `error_ratio = group.count('1')/10`

Answer (score 0):

**Code:-**

```
data="001100111100001111110"
i=0
while i<len(data)-9:
    print("Group"+str(i)+": "+data[i:i+10]+"\t Percentage Error: "+str(data[i:i+10].count('1')/10))
    i+=1
```

**Output:-**

```
Group0: 0011001111   Percentage Error: 0.6
Group1: 0110011110   Percentage Error: 0.6
Group2: 1100111100   Percentage Error: 0.6
Group3: 1001111000   Percentage Error: 0.5
Group4: 0011110000   Percentage Error: 0.4
Group5: 0111100001   Percentage Error: 0.5
Group6: 1111000011   Percentage Error: 0.6
Group7: 1110000111   Percentage Error: 0.6
Group8: 1100001111   Percentage Error: 0.6
Group9: 1000011111   Percentage Error: 0.6
Group10: 0000111111  Percentage Error: 0.6
Group11: 0001111110  Percentage Error: 0.6
```